# pattern to replace "1/3" by "1/3.0"

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex pattern that changes "15 + 15/22 - 16/33.0" into "15 + 15/22.0 - 16/33.0" (change the division by an integer with the division by a float). My attempt so far:

```
        string test = "15 + 15/22 - 16/33.0";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(/[0-9]+[^\.])", RegexOptions.None);
        test = regex.Replace(test, "$1.0");
```

returns the result `"15 + 15/22 .0- 16/33.0.0"` which has a space in "22. 0" and ends with ".0.0", which is not what I would expect. Who can do better?

Comment: Why you want to achieve this. This is not looking too smart to me. Also subtraction in string ...

Comment: He could be doing this simply to be doing this. It could be a mathematical writing convention that he wants to enforce. It could be many things. How can you expect to find it "smart" (useful, I suppose?) without knowing the purpose? I'm aware that you indeed asked for the purpose, but still I find the second half of your comment annoyingly premature and of no value.

Comment: Why? This is a typical input by a user. My program forwards it to a C# compiler to run it, to evaluate the code and return the result. The user expects a float division, while C# performs a integer division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lookarounds.

```
(?<=\/)(\d+)\b(?!\.)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pC4hU6/2)

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=/)(\d+)\b(?!\.)", "$1.0");
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\/)` Positive lookbehind assertion which asserts that the match must be preceded by a forward slash.
- `(\d+)` Captures one or more digit characters.
- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word character and non-word character.
- `(?!\.)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a dot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
string test = "15 + 15/22 - 16/33.0";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(/[0-9]+)([^\.0-9])", RegexOptions.None);
test = regex.Replace(test, "$1.0$2");
```